# Setting priority on console applications

Tags: .net, vb.net, compact-framework

Is there a way to start a console application with low priority?
I have a Forms-Application running on Windows Mobile 6.5 (.NET CF 2.0) which calls a console application like this:

```
Dim myprocess As New ProcessStartInfo()
myprocess.FileName = "myprocess.exe"
myprocess.Arguments = "myarguments"
myprocess.UseShellExecute = False
Process.Start(myprocess)
```

How could I set the priority of this process after starting it?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass` Indicates the priority that the system associates with a process. This value, together with the priority value of each thread of the process, determines each thread's base priority level.

`BelowNormal` specifies that the process has priority above Idle but below Normal.

Invoke this before you load for Form or anywhere you want to change the Process priority.

```
Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = _
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal
```

**UPDATE**

`.NET Compact Framework 2.0` supports threading where you can set the thread priority. Off the top of my head.

```
Imports System.Threading

    Dim yourThread As Thread
    yourThread = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    yourThread.Start()
    yourThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal

Private Sub ThreadTask()

      'Whatever you want to do

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like `PriorityClass`is not available within the compact framework though...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Did you tried using `System.Threading` and `YourThread.Priority`?

Comment: Thread priority does work, I've used it before. I haven't tried to set process priority in Windows Mobile before, so you'll have to look in that more if the thread priority isn't enough. If you cannot do it in the CF, you can probably do it via P/Invoke of the Windows API